# PHP how to clear memory when refreshing

Tags: php

I am facing the following issue. I have a simple textarea where user will use to submit text which is subsequently written to a text file in the server. This is working.

But when I refresh the page it adds in the last added text into the text file again causing duplicate entries.

Any idea what I must do to prevent this? Below is the code I used for the textarea portion.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="text_box" size="50"/>
            <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text_box'])) { 
        $a = $_POST['text_box'];
        $myFile = "textfile.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $a."\r\n");
        fclose($fh);
    }
?>
```

Comment: As an aside: `file_put_contents($myFile, "$a\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`

Answer (score 1):

Pages that are loaded via POST will cause the browser to ask the user to resubmit the information to view the page resulting in the actions performed by that page happening again. If the pages is requested via GET and has variables in the querystring the same thing happens but silently (without the user being prompted to d it again).

The best to work around this is to use the [POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern](http://www.andypemberton.com/engineering/the-post-redirect-get-pattern/). I used it in an example about [processing payments that I wrote for Authorize.Net](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-6-Preventing-Duplicate-Submissions/ba-p/11168). Hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: IIRC, Authorize actually guards against this potential issue ... needless to say, it should not happen in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler so
You can just store a simple hash on session and regenerate it every time.
When the user reloads the page the php wont be executed.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text_box']) && $_SESSION['formFix'] == $_POST['fix']) { 
        $a = $_POST['text_box'];
        $myFile = "textfile.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $a."\r\n");
        fclose($fh);
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="text_box" size="50"/>
            <?php 
                $value = md5(rand(1,999999));
                $_SESSION['formFix'] = $value;
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="fix" value="<?= $value; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

ps: the order of the blocks will matter, so you need to invert em.

Answer (score 0):

As John said, you need to redirect user after form submit.

```
fclose($fh);
// and
header("Location: success.php or where else");
exit;
```

Note: Your redirection won't work unless `ob_start` is not called before, cos your page contains html outputs.

// form.php

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<html>
    <body>
        <? if (isset($_GET['success'])): ?>
        Submit OK! <a href="form.php">New submit</a>
        <? else: ?>
        <form name="form" method="post" action="form.php">
            <input type="text" name="text_box" size="50"/>
            <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
        <? endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text_box'])) { 
        $a = $_POST['text_box'];
        $myFile = "textfile.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $a."\r\n");
        fclose($fh);
        // send user
        header("Location: form.php?success=1");
        exit;
    }
?>
```